# Gradle build-cache superseded build cache

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

[Build file 'F:\GOOGLE PROJECTS\MusicPlayer-dev\app\build.gradle' line: 1

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> The option 'android.enableBuildCache' is deprecated.
> The current default is 'false'.
> It was removed in version 7.0 of the Android Gradle plugin.
> The Android-specific build caches were superseded by the Gradle build cache (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_cache.html).

[image: 1]

Answer (score 18):

I had the same issue.
[image: Picture with Error]

Resolved it by removing the android.enableBuildCache from parent C:\Users<Username>.gradle\gradle.properties  [Or ~/.gradle/gradle.properties]

[image]

Comment: Worked for me too. I have also added to the gradle.properties this line "android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false" as suggested by another question's reply

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the gradle user home directory fixed this for me. On Linux this is `~/.gradle`. I think it's `C:\Users\<Username>\.gradle` on Windows.

Before that, I also updated my systems Java installation and made `[project-dir]/gradlew` executable, but I don't think these steps are actually part of the solution.